# Difficulty understanding the usage of VBOs

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

So I'm trying to implement VBOs but I can't find a good tutorial or documentation of the proper usage of them. I'm guessing you make a VBO when some object needs it and then when the next frame comes about it's drawn/redrawn. But here is where I'm confused:

- How do I draw multiple VBOs?
- How do I modify a VBO?
- When and where do I make a new VBO?

I'm really sorry and I'm just learning OpenGL so excuse me for that! But it's hard to find a tutorial that doesn't just make one VBO, and doesn't make that VBO at the same time it's drawn.

Mainly what I'm asking for is a better understanding of how VBOs work, where they are stored, and how they are drawn. How many VBOs is too many? When I call `glVertexPointer()` what exactly happens with stored VBOs? What if I'm trying to draw VBOs of different types? (just use triangles?)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I draw multiple VBOs?

VBOs are data storage, just like textures. There's a function called `glBindBuffer` which binds a VBO for subsequent access through `glVertexAttribPointer`.

> How do I modify a VBO?

`glBufferSubData`

or

```
buf = glMapBuffer(...);
modify_on(buf);
glUnmapBuffer(...);
```

> When and where do I make a new VBO?

Whenever the existing VBOs no longer can satisfy your demands. Either because they're to small, full or don't match your data type.